# ActiveAdmin add button "previous"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am trying to add two button "previous", "next" to ActiveAdmin show page.

```
action_item only:[:show] do |recipe|
    link_to "Previous", admin_recipe_path(Recipe.where(["id > ?", recipe.id]).first)
end
```

This will leads to

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/recipes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

If I add .id inside admin_recipe_path, it shows ``` undefined method ``id' for nil:NilClass ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd settle with this...

```
action_item only: :show do
  id = Recipe.where('id < ?', recipe.id).order('id DESC').first
  link_to 'Previous', admin_recipe_path(id: id)
end
```